# how to enable remote debugging from window machine to Ubuntu machine via netbeans

Tags: java, ubuntu, netbeans

I want to run remote debugging from Netbeans IDE, OS for remote PC is Ubuntu. 
Ubuntu has got some firewall setup, how do I enable it to allow request(remote debugging) from Windows pc?
The application running in Ubuntu is not a web application

Comment: Are you using Java or some other programming language?

Comment: I am using java

Answer (score 0):

I changed the run script and added debug command to execute my jar in debug mode

java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:server=y,transport=dt_socket,address=,suspend=n appname

Configure Netbeans, using attach debugger mentioning remote host IP and port number (same port number used in debug script).
Then stopped firewall in Ubuntu (remote host), as it is ours by running the following command

systemctl stop firewalld

Started the application in debug mode
Clicked attach debugger and OK from Netbeans after setting breakpoint